# Use ng2 iq select2 to Set a value

Tags: angular, input

I am using an input with angular 2 ng2-iq-select2 (https://github.com/Innqube/ng2-iq-select2) and there is no way, apparently to set a value.

An idea ? is it possible to go around this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this question was some months ago, but just in case anyone else lands here...

The `ng2-iq-select2` component is made to work with angular forms. So what you can do to select a value is to define a form and patch the value the `ng2-iq-select2` component is representing. In case you want to set the value by setting the id only (that's the `referenceMode='id'`) you will also need to provide an implementation for the `selectedProvider` which will be responsible to get the actual data and show it on your form.

You can also use the `[(ngModel)]` directive to set the value, in case you are not working with reactive forms.

I hope this makes things clearer. There are examples in the project's github. (look in `app.component.ts`. Values are being set in the moment of the formgroup creation, but you will get the idea probably)